# Heroku pg:psql command throwing psql: FATAL: database "'" does not exist

Tags: python, postgresql, heroku

heroku pg:psql command throws error when trying to connect to the db.

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Mevin\Desktop\poster> heroku pg:psql
---> Connecting to HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE_URL (DATABASE_URL)
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "--set" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "PROMPT2='posterback::ROSE%R%#" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "'" ignored
psql: warning: extra command-line argument "dbg2gm01rci0jp" ignored
psql: FATAL:  database "'" does not exist
```

Here's my output for `heroku pg:info`

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Mevin\Desktop\poster> heroku pg:info
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE_URL (DATABASE_URL)
Plan:        Hobby-dev
Status:      available
Connections: 0
PG Version:  9.3.3
Created:     2014-03-02 07:22 UTC
Data Size:   7.0 MB
Tables:      9
Rows:        19/10000 (In compliance)
Fork/Follow: Unsupported
Rollback:    Unsupported
```

So why am I not able to access pg:psql ?

Comment: The same problem is happening to me since yesterday, but I haven't changed anything so I think it might be some Heroku problem. I submitted a ticket to Heroku support. Let's see what they tell me. I'm also using heroku pg:psql from Windows.

Comment: Any updates on the ticket you raised ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku did some changes and it may not be working on some Windows versions. The solution I got was:

1) run the following command:

```
heroku config:get your_database_url --app your_app_name
```

This command will give you the complete URL to your database on amazon (let's say url_to_db_amazon)

2) run the following command:

```
psql --set "PROMPT1=your_app_name::database_color%R%#" --set "PROMPT2=your_app_name::database_color%R%#" url_to_db_amazon
```

or just:

```
psql url_to_db_amazon
```

This worked for me.

Comment: What Pablo suggested should work here. We made some changes to give a nicer prompt and it looks like they don't work right on Windows. I'm working on a fix and we should have it in a new updated Toolbelt update later this week. I apologize for the inconvenience.

- Maciek, Heroku Postgres

Comment: I have just received an email from Heroku telling me that a new version that corrects this error is available. You can upgrade heroku running "heroku update" from the command line. Meanwhile you can use the answer I gave. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it from bash instead of the command prompt. There's a good bash you get by install Github for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The database(parse url) specified on the config/database.php file should be on one line.